# Issue in reading text corpus for Glove word embeddings Implementation

Tags: python, nlp, word-embedding

I am trying to train my text corpus using Glove implementation as mentioned in this link https://github.com/hans/glove.py/blob/master/glove.py.I have created a text-corpus of words separated by a single space.The size of the file is 3.6 GB.I am getting this error when I am trying to load the file.

```
2017-08-09 12:51:47,848 Fetching vocab..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Glove_python_bbc.py", line 378, in <module>
    main(parse_args())
  File "Glove_python_bbc.py", line 347, in main
    vocab = get_or_build(arguments.vocab_path, build_vocab, corpus)
  File "Glove_python_bbc.py", line 83, in get_or_build
    obj = msgpack.load(obj_f, use_list=False, encoding='utf-8')
  File "msgpack\_unpacker.pyx", line 164, in msgpack._unpacker.unpack (msgpack/_unpacker.cpp:2622)
  File "msgpack\_unpacker.pyx", line 143, in msgpack._unpacker.unpackb (msgpack/_unpacker.cpp:2143)
msgpack.exceptions.ExtraData: unpack(b) received extra data.
```

Help me read the file.Thanks

Comment: got the same issue! Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam The issue is due to reading huge file at the same time.